# Powershell - Convert foreach to foreach-object -parallel

Tags: powershell

First of all, I will admit that I am not very experienced with Powershell.  So please be gentle.

I have a Powershell script that I use to collect perfmon counters and put those into a SQL database.  However, it is very slow and I want to speed it up.  Here is the original script:

```
$SQLInstanceName = "SQLSRV1"
$DatabaseName = "DBA"
$Counters = 'Processor,\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time','Memory,\Memory\Available Bytes','PhysicalDisk,\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read','PhysicalDisk,\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write','PhysicalDisk,\PhysicalDisk(*)\% Idle Time','Network Interface,\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec','Network Interface,\Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth','SQLServer:Buffer Manager,\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Page life expectancy'


$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLInstanceName;
Initial Catalog=$DatabaseName;
Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 
$conn.open()
 
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 
$cmd.connection = $conn

try
{
    foreach ($ctval in $Counters)
    {
    $Counters = $ctval.Substring($ctval.IndexOf(',') + 1,$ctval.Length - $ctval.IndexOf(',') - 1)
 
    $Prc = Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 4
 
    $Val = $Prc.CounterSamples | Select-Object Path, InstanceName, @{Name = "Timestamp"; Expression= {$_.timestamp}} , @{Name = "CookedValue"; Expression= {IF(($Counters -like '\Process(*') -OR ($Counters -like '\System*')) {$_.CookedValue/$env:number_of_processors} else {$_.CookedValue}}}
 
    foreach ($Info in $Val)
    {
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Perfmon (DateTime,Path,CounterName,InstanceName,ObjectName,Value)
    VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')" -f $Info.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),$Info.Path,$ctval.Substring($ctval.LastIndexOf('\')+1),$Info.InstanceName,$ctval.Substring(0,$ctval.IndexOf(',')),$Info.CookedValue
 
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
    } 

}
catch
{
 
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error -source 'PSPC' -Message $_.Exception.Message -EventId 1234
$conn.close()
}

$conn.close()
```

To speed it up I wanted to make it get perfmon data in parallel.  I tried using a workflow but then the $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() was not valid.  I also have tried using ForEach-Object -Parallel like below but no results are returned.  I am sure that I am not looping through the $Counters array correctly but cannot find why.  Help!  If I should do something totally different, please just point me at the better way....I don't expect someone to write this for me....just need a pointer so I can figure this out.

```
    $Counters | ForEach-Object -Parallel 
    {
    $Counters = $ctval.Substring($ctval.IndexOf(',') + 1,$ctval.Length - $ctval.IndexOf(',') - 1)
 
    $Prc = Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 4
 
    $Val = $Prc.CounterSamples | Select-Object Path, InstanceName, @{Name = "Timestamp"; Expression= {$_.timestamp}} , @{Name = "CookedValue"; Expression= {IF(($Counters -like '\Process(*') -OR ($Counters -like '\System*')) {$_.CookedValue/$env:number_of_processors} else {$_.CookedValue}}}
 

    foreach ($Info in $Val)
    {
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Perfmon (DateTime,Path,CounterName,InstanceName,ObjectName,Value)
    VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')" -f $Info.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),$Info.Path,$ctval.Substring($ctval.LastIndexOf('\')+1),$Info.InstanceName,$ctval.Substring(0,$ctval.IndexOf(',')),$Info.CookedValue
 
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
    }
```

Comment: [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) has no iterator variable; to refer to the pipeline input at hand, you must use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_). With `-Parallel`, you must use the [`$using:` scope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) to refer to any variable values defined _outside_ the script block.

Comment: Also, as an aside: properly indenting your code would make it easier for others to understand the structure of your code.